# Setting up and using ActiveMQ on remote server (hosted on AWS)

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, apache-camel, activemq-classic

We have a an AWS setup with an infrastructure of servers.

I am not sure that AWS is the issue.

One server is running ActiveMQ 5.11.

We have an application using Camel and Spring to instantiate the beans, queue and topics.

When starting the application on separate server from the activeMQ instance we keep getting the message saying Failover failed to connect to localhost:61616

To get around this issue for the time being we installed activeMQ on the same server, which kind of defeats the idea.

The spring context is quite vanilla and appears to start, from what I have seen to look at in the admin. the server is connected to by the initial context, but the connect is not maintained and fails over to the localhost install.

I have been looking into what we must do, but I have so far been unable to find what I am after, I have enabled all Traffic between the servers so make sure that there aren't any ports being blocked, but no matter what I have tried the connect appears to drop the remote server in favour of the localhost.

I will keep plugging away as this is a major requirement for our project.

Comment: If your activemq is on different server, then you need to check that your application doesn't contain localhost as url in any activemq setting. Also check that you have open TCP port 61616 on that server

Comment: I do have all traffic set on both servers, and the remote host url is set in /etc/hosts

Comment: what about in your application, have you set the remote host url there ?

Comment: <beans:bean id="connectionFactory"
  class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"> 
  <beans:property name="brokerURL" value="tcp://<REMOTE_HOST_URL>:61616" />
 </beans:bean>

Comment: yep that is all set, like is say I have checked the admin and it appears to create some information on the server, but it fails to then use them.

Comment: I am currently looking into prefixing with the connectionFactory (As far as I can work out?) `to(queueFactory + ":topic:" + landingAreaReceipt)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got this working, this is fairly new to me, so I wasnt sure what I was doing for one.

A post helped a bit, but still wasnt that clear (mainly because our work firewall blocks cdns!) and I cannot find it now!

the pattern is `connectionId:queue|topic:identifying.words`

I had `connectionId` set to `activemq` which didnt exist anywhere.

I logged onto the admin and create this.

Then updated the following code

```
logger.debug("Setup Context");
String transport = ApplicationProperties.getProperty("activemq.transport");
logger.info(transport);

// Not sure if this is a queue or not, but it is basically a name pointer.
String queue = ApplicationProperties.getProperty("activemq.queue");
logger.info(queue);         

ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new activeMQConnectionFactory(transport);

camelContext.addComponent(queue,JmsComponent.jmsComponent(connectionFactory));
```

So the correct format for the `from` or `to` is:

```
String jmsLandingAreaReceipt = queue + ":topic:" + landingAreaReceipt;
```